# Meteor and reactive 'distinct'

Tags: meteor

Suppose I have a collection with field `foo`, and I'd like to get the count of unique values.

```
Collection.distinct('foo').length;
```

I would like to have the value available in my template, such as `{{ fooCount }}`.

How could I do this, and have the number be reactive in Meteor?

Comment: Have you followed the extended exampl in the publish documentation already? (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) Look for `count-by-room`.

Comment: Yes, the above plus a package to add server side aggregation with distinct() should get you what you want. This one is widely used: https://atmospherejs.com/monbro/mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
Template.yourTemplateName.helpers({
         fooCount() {
           var foos = CollectionName.find({foo: {$exists: true}})
                                    .map(d => d.foo);
           return _.uniq(foos).length;

         }
});
```

this will be reactive because it is a template helper using a reactive data source. Note the use of [underscores](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) with is part of core meteor.

also, just for fun you could do this:

```
Template.yourTemplateName.helpers({
             fooCount() {
               return CollectionName.find({foo: {$exists: true}})
                        .map(d => d.foo)
                        .reduce((acc, b) => _.contains(acc, b) ? 
                                              acc : acc.concat(b), []).length

             }
    });
```

Comment: This is only if the publication publishes the entire Collection. What if you only want to publish a cursor of a Collection on a query of a field with distinct results?  Good luck on that.